# Android Local Alarm Notification

Tags: android, notifications, alarm

I have an android project I want to do something like this in this project. The first application system time is 8.30 hours by phone will send notification of the above said good morning etc. 10:30 Goodnight evening when he will send a message. I know the events of the local Notification application continuously active, but watch the time of the phone is important and how do I reset the phone to monitor the system clock when the application continues to run in the background again. Furthermore, the application will not open at all hours, for example 8, the application will take notice again.

Comment: What have you tried? There are lots of examples of doing this on the web - find one, try to get it working and come back with specific questions.  You are asking too much (and asking the SO community to architect your basic app).

Comment: i tried local intent thats worked.but i used system.milis code that not worked with local notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have mention full code of local notification. Try this code [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674739/how-to-create-status-bar-notification-which-is-displayed-every-30-seconds-even-w/31674883?noredirect=1#comment51494481_31674883).

I hope this full code help for you.. Thanks.. :)

Comment: Thank you Bro.But I need still how can I run a class with alarm.Example everyday 18:00 o'clock main.class will run in background.

Comment: okay. You can make one new condition 'if(TodayDateTimeMiliSecond <= ConvertMiliSecond(TodayDate+yourTime) &&  TodayDateTimeMiliSecond >=(ConvertMiliSecond(TodayDate+yourTime) - 60000)
)' just above a call intent  in "AlarmReceiver.java Class". try it this.. :)

Comment: Bro thank you for this comment but I'm noob at android can u write a simple code or tutorial url ? Thank you soo much.